# Dynamicaly update dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, updates

I want to dynamically create a dictionary according to the items in a list that has to be append. So I tried:

```
questions = 'my_question'
answers = ['thisisanswer1','thisisanswer2','thisisanswer3']
answers = {"Answer{i}":answers[i] for i in range(0,len(answers))}
dict_replacing = {'Questions': questions}.update(answers)
```

But it returns `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code as suggested by others in comments.

1. There is a missing assignment variable `i`
2. The dictionary key is a string literal `Answer{i}` which will be same in every iteration and will overwrite the previous dictionary key.
3. The dictionary updation and assignment statement `dict_replacing = {'Questions': questions}.update(answers)` # this will return the result of the update operation ie `None`

```
questions = "my_question"
answers = ["thisisanswer1", "thisisanswer2", "thisisanswer3"]

answers = {f"Answer{i}": answers[i] for i in range(0, len(answers))}

dict_replacing = {"Questions": questions, **answers}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the`i` between `for` and `in`.
Also, before`"answer{i}"` put an `f`.

Comment: On top of that problem, they forgot to have more than one key. They probably wanted `f"Answer{i}"`, not `"Answer{i}"`. And the comprehension is better written with `enumerate`, making it `{f"Answer{i}": answer for i, answer in enumerate(answers)}`